# omniauth and google with sinatra on heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, omniauth

I'm trying to use OmniAuth in a sinatra app with google as the login provider.  Using the twitter and facebook providers work fine:

```
require 'omniauth'
require 'openid'
require 'openid/store/filesystem'


use OmniAuth::Builder do
use OmniAuth::Strategies::OpenID, OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('./tmp'), :name => 'google', :identifier => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id'  
end

get '/sign_in'
  redirect '/auth/google'
end
```

Thoughts?  When the browser tries to get '/auth/google', it gets a 503 - Service Unavailable.  There is nothing in the heroku logs

Thoughts or suggestions on what this might be?

I just started a bounty on this question - what I'm hoping for is a sample implementation that works on heroku.

---

I increased the log level on heroku.  Here is what I'm getting now:

```
2011-07-07T16:15:09+00:00 heroku[nginx]: GET /sign_in/?p=google HTTP/1.1 | 207.224.213.179 | 269 | http | 302
2011-07-07T16:15:09+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2011-07-07T09:15:09.863397 #1]  INFO -- OpenID: Error attempting to use stored discovery information: OpenID::TypeURIMismatch
2011-07-07T16:15:09+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2011-07-07T09:15:09.863480 #1]  INFO -- OpenID: Attempting discovery to verify endpoint
2011-07-07T16:15:09+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2011-07-07T09:15:09.863512 #1]  INFO -- OpenID: Performing discovery on https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawlAKE9QAQb9mMRyYCCmAkEYIcqfmhrA080
2011-07-07T16:15:09+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2011-07-07T09:15:09.865033 #1]  INFO -- OpenID: WARNING: making https request to https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawlAKE9QAQb9mMRyYCCmAkEYIcqfmhrA080 without verifying server certificate; no CA path was specified.
2011-07-07T16:15:09+00:00 app[web.1]: 207.224.213.179 - - [07/Jul/2011 09:15:09] "POST /auth/google/callback HTTP/1.1" 302 - 0.0956
2011-07-07T16:15:09+00:00 heroku[router]: GET myurl.com/auth/google/callback dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=100ms status=302 bytes=0
```

Comment: Did you take a look at [this](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Sinatra-Example)?

Comment: Yep the twitter provider works great.  I just want to get google working too. B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page at https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/OpenID-and-Google-Apps gives two possible solutions:

> On Heroku you can change the path to "./tmp" or use Memcached.

It seems like you already tried the Memcached solution - do you have a Memcached instance running and properly setup on Heroku?

Comment: I wasn't able to get memcached to work.  Heroku requires dalli and dalli apparently doesn't quite work with Open ID's memcache store.  I changed the path to ./tmp and now it goes to google, asks me to authorize the app, returns to my site, but doesn't log me in.  Still looks like it isn't finding the store properly.

Comment: It did not solved the probolem. Ok, disabling protect_from_forgery seems to fix this, but I would like a better solution

Answer (score 0):

You could use google's openid to sign in.

```
use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :openid, OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('/tmp')
  use OmniAuth::Strategies::OpenID, OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('/tmp'), :name => 'google', :identifier => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id'
end
```

Comment: That at least doesn't crash.  It goes to google, asks me to grant rights and then comes back, but it doesn't login.  I think the problem might be that heroku's "filesystem" is read-only.  So I'll look into setting up a different openid store.